# Use ansible initialize postgresql multiple times

Tags: database, ansible

Make this task will work the first time:

```yaml
- name: Initialize the Database
  command: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
```

If run it a second time, will get the error:

> fatal: [192.168.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup", "initdb"], "delta": "0:00:00.017590", "end": "2019-12-11 06:08:49.999631", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-12-11 06:08:49.982041", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Data directory is not empty!", "stdout_lines": ["Data directory is not empty!"]}

How to avoid running this task if it already initialized the database on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the file/directory created by initdb is there first and if not, initdb.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

Comment: Thank you. Like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/7v7tro/is_there_a_way_for_my_shell_task_that_checks_if_a/dtqkd6u/

Answer (score 6):

Q: ***"stdout: Data directory is not empty!"***

A: [18.2. Creating a Database Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/creating-cluster.html) says:

> initdb will refuse to run if the data directory exists and already contains files; this is to prevent accidentally overwriting an existing installation.

To make the [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-execute-commands-on-targets) task [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html) use the parameter *creates*, e.g.

```yaml
- name: Initialize the Database
  command: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
  args:
    creates: /usr/local/pgsql/data
```